# PostgreSQL trigger to calculate salaries

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have problems with the following trigger both under PostgreSQL and MySQL. There are bugs in row 3, etc. A trigger should be created, increasing the salary of professors depending on the hours of lectures.

```
create create trigger viellehre after insert on Vorlesungen referencing new as vo_neu foreach row when group by vo_neu.gelesenvon 
having sum(Vorlesungen.SWS) > 5 and 
sum(Vorlesungen.SWS) - vo_neu.SWS <= 5 
update Professoren 
set Professoren.gehalt = Professoren.gehalt * 1.05 
where Professoren.PersNr = vo_neu.gelesenvon;
```

Comment: This isn't PostgreSQL syntax, check the manual and create a trigger function to do the trick.

Comment: create trigger bonus after insert on Vorlesungen ....referencing dont work on postgre? for each row when group by vo_neu.gelesenvon having sum(Vorlesungen.SWS) > 5 and sum(Vorlesungen.SWS) - vo_neu.SWS <= 5 update Professoren set Professoren.gehalt = Professoren.gehalt * 1.05 where Professoren.PersNr = vo_neu.gelesenvon; How is the correct syntax for when group by under postgre with having clause ?

Comment: I've never seen a trigger defined with group-by/having in the WHEN clause. It's not legal in Oracle, I doubt it's legal in Postgres. The logic that you're trying to implement doesn't look amenable to processing with triggers, which in any case tend to make systems hard to debug. It looks like this should go in application code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have such a trigger definition:

*Also, a trigger definition can specify a Boolean WHEN condition, which will be tested to see whether the trigger should be fired. In row-level triggers the WHEN condition can examine the old and/or new values of columns of the row. Statement-level triggers can also have WHEN conditions, although the feature is not so useful for them since the condition cannot refer to any values in the table.*

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createtrigger.html